# PHP return associative array, by multiple element search?

Tags: php

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
$array = array(
    array('Field1' => 'red',  'Field2' => 'green',   'Field3' => 'blue'),
    array('Field1' => 'pink', 'Field2' => 'pinkish', 'Field3' => 'barbiecolor'),
    array('Field1' => 'red',  'Field2' => 'blue', '   Field3' => 'orange')
);
```

And I want to check this by the given values:

```
$searchBy = array('Field1' => 'red', 'Field2' => 'blue');
```

What I want to achieve, is to return the parent array that has all associative key & value pairs matched. I've tried `in_array()` but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 3):

`array_filter` may be better for this:

```
$matches = array_filter($array,function($a) use ($searchBy) {
    foreach($searchBy as $k=>$v) {
        if( $a[$k] != $v) return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Do note the minimal required PHP version though ;)

Comment: Oh yes. This'll work in PHP 5.3, but before that you will need to use [`create_function`](http://php.net/create-function) instead.

Comment: @Kolink - thanks works perfect! In the interest of older versions, how do you define this search function? Thanks

Comment: Something like this: `create_function('$a','global $searchBy; foreach($searchBy as $k=>$v) {if($a[$k] != $v) return false;} return true;');`

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$find = array_filter($array, function ($a) use($searchBy) {
    return array_intersect_assoc($searchBy, $a) == $searchBy;
});
```

[See Live Demo](http://eval.in/17090)

Old School Version

```
$find = find($searchBy, $array);
print_r($find);

// Function used
function find($needle, $haystack) {
    $r = array();
    foreach ( $haystack as $k => $a ) {
        array_intersect_assoc($needle, $a) == $needle and $r[$k] = $a;
    }
    return $r;
}
```

[Old School Demo](http://3v4l.org/lrOC0)

Comment: is it possible to achieve this with PHP < 5.3 ?

Comment: @Matt i won't post it because if am not using loop am forced to use `globals` which i don't believe in http://3v4l.org/IRLu5 but i would update with a simple loop version